# WebCam present problem in recorded video in BigBlueButton

Tags: ruby, video, webcam, bigbluebutton

I need assistance in integrating BBB into my LMS system. I configured the layout to build the recorded video as follows when the screen and webCam (1) are shared at the same time during the recording process.

bigbluebutton\record-and-playback\video\scripts\video.yml

```
layout:
  width: 1280
  height: 720
  framerate: 24
  areas:
    - name: presentation
      x: 0
      y: 0
      width: 1280
      height: 720
    - name: webcam
      x: 0
      y: 0
      width: 1280
      height: 720    
    - name: deskshare
      x: 0
      y: 0
      width: 1280
      height: 720    
      pad: true      
    - name: webcam
      x: 960
      y: 500
      width: 270
      height: 200
```

When using this layout, if both the screen and webCam are shared during the recording process, the video is recorded in the same structure as screen1 as follows.

When using this layout, if both the screen and webCam are shared during the recording process, the screen sharing layout (full-screen) and webCam layout (small) are displayed in the video like the screen1.png file.

[image]

However, even when screen sharing is disabled, the webCam layout (full-screen) and webCam layout (small) are displayed in the video like the screen2.png file.

[image]

I don't want to present a small webCam layout in this case.

Comment: Is there anyway to change layouts when the screen sharing is disabled (without restarting the app)? PS: I don't use BigBlueButton.

Comment: Unfortunately, once the layout is set, it cannot be changed. In other words, a once recorded video consists of only one layout structure.
That is the problem.

Comment: No sure why you're not getting Answers. It's not clear (no code example) about how you disable screen sharing.... For example can you access the **area** by its **name** (as listed in the YAML file) when disabling it through code? if yes, Can a name (in the YAML) be customized like as being `webcam1` and `webcam2`? if yes, Now disable both by their custom names like "deskshare" and "webcam2" (the 270x200 view). Does it work to now only show the main webcam (eg: "webcam1" at 1280x720 view)?

Comment: Thank you for your interesting. If you really want to solve this problem, please contact us directly here. (discord: alphadream0914)